# What are the current best upper bounds of #P?

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat, counting-complexity, upper-bounds, worst-case

[#P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P) is the class of counting problems for problems in NP.  In other words, a solution to #P returns the number of solutions to a particular problem in NP.

I'm wondering if there have been any studies on the worst-case behaviors of current best solutions to problems in NP.  My focus in the past has been on 3-SAT, so I am particularly interested in the time it takes to count 3-SAT solutions in the worst case.  However, I ask in general, **What are the current best upper bounds for any (#P-complete) problem in #P?**

Comment: Do you mean upper bounds for #P-complete problems? Because otherwise you can cook up problems in #P that are trivial to solve.

Comment: @MCH: Yes, I mean #P-complete problems.

Comment: What about PTASs for the permanent ? is that an example ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat: I'd prefer not to include approximations.  Perhaps as a separate question, but I'm really interested in exacting answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One such algorithm for $\#3\operatorname{SAT}$ is due to [Kutzkov](http://www.itu.dk/people/konk/papers/%233-sat.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

I you’re looking for natural problems, you can compute many counting problems on planar graphs in time $\exp(\sqrt n)$ because of the planar separator theorem. For example, everything that can be expressed as a valuation of the Tutte polynomial [1]. Most of these problems remain #P-hard restricted to planar graphs, see [Tutte Polynomial @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial).

[1] K. Sekine, H. Imai, S. Tani, Computing the Tutte polynomial of a graph of moderate size, Algorithms and Computation, 6th International Symposium (ISAAC ’95), Cairns, Australia, December 4–6, 1995, Lecture Notes in Computer Science 1004, Springer, 1995, pp. 224–233.