# What's the upper bounds for #3-SAT circuits?

Tags: sat, upper-bounds

We have, from [this thread on 3-SAT upper bounds](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/best-upper-bounds-on-sat), and [this answer on #P](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/18069/1549) that the current best upper bounds for 3-SAT is faster than $O(1.31)^n$, and approximately $O(1.64^n)$ for #3-SAT.

Can we do better for 3-SAT and #3-SAT *circuits*?

The reason I ask is that I've been fiddling with a circuit that achieves a modest improvement over the #3-SAT upper bounds mentioned above.  But since it's a circuit, I have my doubts that it's even worthwhile.  So I'm wondering:  what kind of circuit upper bounds can we get?